# Cant create database for ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems, terminal

I've just starting ruby on rails and I am still busy setting everything up running.. the problem that I encounter is that it keeps saying that mysql2 is not part of a bundle.. I have googled it obviously but the solutions didn't seem to work

```
sudo gem install mysql2
```

etc..

the stuff I get is

> $ rake db:create
>   rake aborted!
>   Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (mysql2 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:214:in `gem'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:3
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`require'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in`load_dependency'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:50:in`resolve_hash_connection'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:29:in `spec'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:130:in`establish_connection'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `create_database'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:62
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:62:in`each'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:62
>   Tasks: TOP => db:create
>   (See full trace by running task with --trace)

Anyone here knows the solution for me? ( p.s. I see alot people saying that it has to be added to the gem config but how? )

Comment: Read the error page:
`gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter`

Comment: i did.. but it keeps saying the same error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure your `Gemfile` (located in the root of your project) includes

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

Then run the `bundle install` to install it.

I believe the `activerecord-mysql2-adapter` gem is installed as a dependency, but you can also add

```
gem 'activerecord-mysql2-adapter'
```

If it still requests it.

Comment: this did the trick! getting another error still but this one is solved :)